# How do I remove a bone constraint in the middle of an animation meanwhile keeping location

Tags: animation, constraints

Im trying to do a first person animation of unsheathing a sword, i have child of constraint on the sheath with the actual sword as the target, and the actual sword has a child of constraint and target set to the hand bone so that it all moves together. The start is fine but as soon as i try to unsheathe the sword in the animation, after i move the timeline, it clips back. Is it possible for me to remove the child of constraint in the middle of the animation meanwhile keeping its position and rotation ( i tried deleting the constraint after doing the beginning animation but it just reset's its position elsewhere) I can provide any other asked information if needed. Thanks!

Comment: This I imagine is a duplicate.  Insert a  "visual" keyframe. _visual_ in that it is where you see it at that frame, to keep the object at same transform after removing constraints etc.

Comment: If you want to apply more visual keyframes, you need to look for animation "baking".

Comment: Im not really sure how to use visual keyframes, are there any simple tutorials somewhat related to my problem? If i delete the child of constraint, the object just shifts into a default location and thats it @batFINGER

Comment: @moonboots I'm in 2.79, though i could try to recreate it in 2.8 and see if i can animate it there

Comment: Setting the constraint influence to zero is equvalent of deleting it.  Please check out the answers in question marked duplicate. @moonboots the x is an operator (can't be keyframed)  that sets the properties to "visual" values, (look at transform panel when you click it) ...without the keyframe.being inserted.

Comment: oh ok my bad I misunderstood what it was

Comment: I have to say I don't understand the explanations of Sambler on the linked page, anyway you need to give your child object a Child Of constraint with the parent as Target and click Set Inverse, then, the frame just before the dropping, keyframe it > LocRotScale and keyframe the Child Of constraint influence at a value of 1, then, the next frame, keyframe > Visual LocRotScale and keyframe the Child Of constraint influence at a value of 0. Is it what Sambler explains?